# Recurring subscription by paypal express checkout, buyer is paid two time

Tags: express, paypal, checkout, recurring

I created a recurring payment for monthly subscription in my site. User will pay money every month.  But I see that buyer is paid twice for a subscription, one for initiating and one for recurring. 
I read https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/api/merchant/DoExpressCheckoutPayment_API_Operation_NVP/, that we can set PAYMENTREQUEST_n_AMT = 0 in this and SetExpressCheckout to ignore initiating payment. But when I set it to 0, I get error that amout is zero so I can finish checkout. 
How can I create recurring without pay two time. I tried skip DoExpressCheckoutPayment method, but by this way, I can't get transaction ID

Comment: are you setting any initial amount, i have also implemented recurring payment , i haven't face such an issue

Comment: No, I dont set INITAMT in my CreateRecurringPaymentProfile method.
this is parameter I passed in SetExpressCheckout

Comment: below are parameters  in DoExpressCheckoutPayment
$fields = array(    
  'TOKEN' => $checkoutDetails['TOKEN'],
  'PAYMENTACTION' => 'Sale',
  'PAYERID' => $checkoutDetails['PAYERID'],
  'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_AMT' => '5.0',
  'PAYMENTREQUEST_0_CURRENCYCODE' => 'NOK'
  );
And Create profile 
$fields = array(
 'TOKEN'=>urlencode($checkoutDetails['TOKEN']),
 'PAYERID' => urlencode($checkoutDetails['PAYERID']),
 'PROFILESTARTDATE' => time(),
 'DESC' => 'Test',
 'BILLINGPERIOD' => 'Month',
 'BILLINGFREQUENCY' => '1',
 'TOTALBILLINGCYCLES'=> '60',
 'AMT' => '5.0',
 'CURRENCYCODE'=> 'NOK'
  );

Answer (score 1):

When you create a recurring payment you have option to charge user two times - one is related with INITAMT parameter and this get charged immediately from user account. Second is related with BILLINGPERIOD, BILLINGFREQUENCY, TOTALBILLINGCYCLES and REGULARTOTALBILLINGCYCLES paypal parameters, which is related with recurring payment **AFTER** current period of time. The key is to set a payment after the recurring period of time and set a INITAMT to get first payment immediately

For (PHP) example :

```
$padata['BILLINGPERIOD']                    = 'Month';
$padata['BILLINGFREQUENCY']                 = '1';
$padata['TOTALBILLINGCYCLES']               = '12';
$padata['REGULARTOTALBILLINGCYCLES']        = '1';
$padata['INITAMT']                          = 'MONTHLY PRICE';
```

In recurring payments there is no transaction ID but existing subscribe ID in your case this key will be PROFILEID + CORRELATIONID

Comment: Sorry, I would like to charge immediately for first recurring cycle. But I don't want to charge for initiating. If I set INITAMT, that means, buyer is charged 2 times?

Comment: In this case must set paypal parameters like my example

Comment: I tried and see that buyer is charged 2 times like this http://pasteboard.co/1c2htGOT.png 

But I want it charges only one time. Sorry if I missunderstand your comment.

Comment: I skiped DoExpressCheckoutPayment and add parameters as your comment, it works. But do you know how to get transaction id if ignored DoExpressCheckoutPayments method?

Comment: Try with paypal method GetExpressCheckoutDetails

Comment: Thanks. But it doesn't return transaction ID :(

Comment: When you execute the paypal method CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile the method will return all information for current transaction session

Comment: This is what I get from the CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile:

array(7) { ["PROFILEID"]=> string(14) "I-YEN3DW23WG7U" ["PROFILESTATUS"]=> string(14) "PendingProfile" 
["TIMESTAMP"]=> string(20) "2015-10-07T09:15:08Z" ["CORRELATIONID"]=> string(13) "6c9ef21ea1b41" 
["ACK"]=> string(7) "Success" 
"VERSION"]=> string(5) "122.0" 
["BUILD"]=> string(6) "000000" }

Comment: In recurring payments there is no transaction ID but existing subscribe ID in your case this key will be PROFILEID + CORRELATIONID

Answer (score 1):

Following is my application code , First i am calling `setExpressCheckout()` than `getExpressCheckoutDetails()`

than upon recieving token using this piece of code for paying and generating profile

```
if(request.getParameter("token")!= null && request.getParameter("PayerID") != null){
            if(token.contentEquals(request.getParameter("token"))/* && payerID.contentEquals(request.getParameter("PayerID"))*/){
                this.payerID = request.getParameter("PayerID");

                if(doExpressCheckout()){
                    if(createRecurringProfile()){
                        //some notification showing successful order
                        log.debug("Trasaction status : Successfull");
                        license.setProfileID(profileID);
                        license.setActive(true);
                        license.setLicenseType(LicenseBean.PAYMENT_RECURRING);
                        ApplicationInstance.getCurrent().fireEvent("SaveLicense", description, license,false);
                        ApplicationInstance.getCurrent().fireEvent("DisplayLicenseDetails", "Success", license,false);
                    }
```

Following are the four methods

```
public String setExpressCheckout() {
    NVPEncoder encoder = new NVPEncoder();
    NVPDecoder decoder = new NVPDecoder();

    try
    {           

        encoder.add("VERSION", "86.0");         
        encoder.add("METHOD","SetExpressCheckout");
        encoder.add("L_BILLINGTYPE0","RecurringPayments");   
        encoder.add("L_BILLINGAGREEMENTDESCRIPTION0","UserPack");
        // Add request-specific fields to the request string.
        encoder.add("RETURNURL",returnURL);
        encoder.add("CANCELURL",cancelURL); 
        encoder.add("AMT",cost);
        encoder.add("PAYMENTACTION",paymentAction.getValue());
        encoder.add("CURRENCYCODE",currencyCode.getValue());

        // Execute the API operation and obtain the response.
        String NVPRequest= encoder.encode();
        String NVPResponse =caller.call(NVPRequest);
        decoder.decode(NVPResponse);

    } 
    catch(PayPalException pe){
        log.error("Paypal Exception:", pe.getCause());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.error(ex);
    }
    return decoder.get("TOKEN");
}

public boolean getExpressCheckoutDetails(String token)
{

    NVPEncoder encoder = new NVPEncoder();
    NVPDecoder decoder = new NVPDecoder();

    try
    {
        encoder.add("VERSION", "86.0");
        encoder.add("METHOD", "GetExpressCheckoutDetails");

        // Add request-specific fields to the request string.
        // Pass the token value returned in SetExpressCheckout.
        encoder.add("TOKEN", token);

        // Execute the API operation and obtain the response.
        String NVPRequest = encoder.encode();
        String NVPResponse = caller.call(NVPRequest);
        decoder.decode(NVPResponse);
        //          payerID = decoder.get("PAYERID");
        payerName = decoder.get("PAYERNAME");

    }catch (Exception ex)
    {
        log.error(ex);
    }

    if(decoder.get("ACK").toLowerCase().contains("success")){
        this.token = token;
        return true;
    }
    else{
        return false;
    }
}

public boolean createRecurringProfile() 
{
    NVPEncoder encoder = new NVPEncoder();
    NVPDecoder decoder = new NVPDecoder();

    try
    {
        encoder.add("VERSION", "86.0");
        encoder.add("METHOD","CreateRecurringPaymentsProfile");

        encoder.add("DESC","UserPack");//    #Profile description - same as billing agreement description
        encoder.add("BILLINGPERIOD","Month");//    #Period of time between billings
        encoder.add("BILLINGFREQUENCY","1");//    #Frequency of charges 

        //          encoder.add("INITAMT","25.29");
        //          encoder.add("FAILEDINITAMTACTION","ContinueOnFailure");

        // Add request-specific fields to the request string.
        // Pass the token value by actual value returned in the SetExpressCheckout.
        encoder.add("TOKEN",token);
        encoder.add("PAYERID",payerID);
        Date localTime = new Date(); 
        //creating DateFormat for converting time from local timezone to GMT(as specified in paypal)
        DateFormat converter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");

        encoder.add("PROFILESTARTDATE",converter.format(localTime));//SimpleDateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date())

        encoder.add("AMT",cost);
        encoder.add("CURRENCYCODE","USD");//    #The currency, e.g. US dollars
        encoder.add("COUNTRYCODE","US");//    #The country code, e.g. US  
        encoder.add("MAXFAILEDPAYMENTS","3");
        //          encoder.add("PAYMENTACTION",paymentAction.getValue());
        encoder.add("CURRENCYCODE",currencyCode.getValue());
        // Execute the API operation and obtain the response.
        String NVPRequest = encoder.encode();
        String NVPResponse =caller.call(NVPRequest);
        decoder.decode(NVPResponse);
        profileID = decoder.get("PROFILEID");
        profileStatus = decoder.get("PROFILESTATUS");
        //transactionID = decoder.get("TRANSACTIONID");
        paymentDate = decoder.get("PAYMENTDATE");
        log.debug("Paypal acknowledgement: "+decoder.get("ACK"));
        //System.out.println("Paypal acknowledgement: "+decoder.get("ACK"));
    } 
    catch(PayPalException pe){
        log.error("Paypal Exception:", pe.getCause());
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        log.error("Error :",ex.getCause());
    }

    if(decoder.get("ACK").toLowerCase().contains("success")){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        //System.out.println("Paypal error: "+decoder.get("L_SHORTMESSAGE0"));
        log.error("Paypal error: "+decoder.get("L_SHORTMESSAGE0"));
        return false;
    }
}


public boolean doExpressCheckout() 
{
    NVPEncoder encoder = new NVPEncoder();
    NVPDecoder decoder = new NVPDecoder();

    try
    {
        encoder.add("VERSION", "51.0");
        encoder.add("METHOD","DoExpressCheckoutPayment");

        // Add request-specific fields to the request string.
        // Pass the token value by actual value returned in the SetExpressCheckout.
        encoder.add("TOKEN",token);
        encoder.add("PAYERID",payerID);
        encoder.add("AMT",cost);
        encoder.add("PAYMENTACTION",paymentAction.getValue());
        encoder.add("CURRENCYCODE",currencyCode.getValue());
        // Execute the API operation and obtain the response.
        String NVPRequest = encoder.encode();
        String NVPResponse =caller.call(NVPRequest);
        decoder.decode(NVPResponse);
        //transactionID = decoder.get("TRANSACTIONID");
        paymentDate = decoder.get("PAYMENTDATE");
        log.debug("Paypal acknowledgement: "+decoder.get("ACK"));
        //System.out.println("Paypal acknowledgement: "+decoder.get("ACK"));
    } 
    catch(PayPalException pe){
        log.error("Paypal Exception:", pe.getCause());
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        log.error("Error :",ex.getCause());
    }

    if(decoder.get("ACK").toLowerCase().contains("success")){
        return true;
    }
    else{
        //System.out.println("Paypal error: "+decoder.get("L_SHORTMESSAGE0"));
        log.error("Paypal error: "+decoder.get("L_SHORTMESSAGE0"));
        return false;
    }
}
```